# magento setup:di:compile crashes: Warning: array_replace_recursive(): Argument #1 is not an array in Writer.php on line 135

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile, uninstall-module

I uninstalled a module with command:

```
magento module:disable Dotdigitalgroup_Email
```

and once I run:

```
magento setup:di:compile
```

I get this error message:

```
Warning: array_replace_recursive(): Argument #1 is not an array in /home/playsports/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Deploy
  mentConfig/Writer.php on line 135
```

I'm on Centos, PHP7.1

[image]

Comment: I also have an error when I run magento setup:upgrade (as seen in the picture) I am not certain they relate so I just want to figure out this one first as it won't let me get my store back up and I need to compile...

Answer (score 0):

OK for anyone else who ever runs into this issue the problem was that the env.php file got corrupted somehow when disabling the module (in /app/etc).
I did not have a backup, so I found one available online: https://github.com/emizentech/magento2/blob/master/app/etc/env.php.sample
I used that to build it again and once complete I copied it into the /app/etc directory.

I still think this is a core issue as somehow this file got overwritten, and it shouldn't have... but anyhow.